# Identifying Which Toggle Was Toggled - Office UI Fabric - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to use multiple toggles in my add-in but having trouble identifying which one was toggled.

I am able to get the id of the toggle in most cases, but if a user clicks on the smaller knob within the toggle, I am unable to get the toggle's id.
[image]

From the example above, if I click on the toggle thumb, where the red arrow points, I get the following output as the `target.id`
[image: Target id of Toggle Thumb]

I have no way to identify which toggle this came from and do not believe I can set the id of the toggle thumb.

When the user clicks anywhere in the green sections, I get the following log where I can grab the ID and do conditional logic.

[image: Target id of Toggle]

Before reporting this as a bug on github, I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong. I came across this which was similar but not what I am looking for: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/6753

This code pen will show the issue:
https://codepen.io/rocketlobster5/pen/eYOvGjz

Comment: I have added it here: https://codepen.io/rocketlobster5/pen/eYOvGjz @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it should considered as a bug, to get the element that the event listener is attached to [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) should be used instead of `target`.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve id of toggle element:

```
private handleChange(ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked: boolean) {
   console.log(ev.currentTarget["id"]);
}
```

[Modified codepen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/gOYmzxm?editors=1111)